# How to map a function in Numpy under conditions

Tags: python, numpy

Given a Numpy array (actually a 3 channels image) I need to map a function on it, only where a triplette (aka RGB pixel) satisfies a predefined condition. All the rest should be kept untouched.

I know how to set a constant value when a pixel meets a certain condition, but I don't know how to apply a function having as parameter the value of such pixel.

For instance, the following example allows to set to 128 all the pixels that have all the channels greater than 128:

```
import numpy as np

L = 128
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 5, 3))
img[(img > L).all(axis=2)] = np.array([128, 128, 128])
```

But, what about if I have to set a value dependent on the current value of the pixel ?
The following code of course does not work:

```
import numpy as np

def smart_function(v):
    return v//2

L = 128
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 5, 3))
img[(img > L).all(axis=2)] = smart_function(img)
```

I also tried with vectorize with no success:

```
import numpy as np

def smart_function(v):
    return v//2

vf = np.vectorize(smart_function)

L = 128
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 5, 3))
img[(img > L).all(axis=2)] = vf(img)
```

**Edit**
To explain better my request, this is the expected behaviour written in plain Python. Obviously this code is very slow, so unusable, but it gives the idea:

```
for y in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x in range(img.shape[1]):
        pixel = img[y, x]
        if pixel[0] > L and pixel[1] > L and pixel[2] > L:
            img[y, x] = smart_function(pixel)
```

Comment: You could use your condition to create a mask and than apply smart_function on masked array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `frompyfunc` with `at`:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.random.randn(5, 5)

def f(x):
  return np.round(x)

f = np.frompyfunc(f, nin=1, nout=1)

f.at(xs, xs > 0)
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. The only problem I see is that I need the whole triplette passed to the function (smart_function is more complex than the one I reported), so basically the entire RGB array related to the selected point. Is there a way to do it ?